# Optimal Multi-Level Quoting for Market Making

Tags: market-microstructure, market-making

I have been studying limit order books with focus on the optimal quoting problem for market makers. I have read the Avellaneda-Stoikov model and the subsequent developments. However I am unable to find any papers that quote on multiple levels. It would be very helpful if someone could point me towards such papers.

Thanks!!!!